# Return of Oracle Stored Procedure using OracleDataReader (ODAC)

Tags: c#, odp.net, odac

I have a problem with output data from Oracle Stored Procedure using OracleDataReader(Oracle.DataAccess.Client).

Procedure:

```
    procedure LOAD_BL_REQ_2(P_XML CLOB, P_XML_OUT out CLOB) is
    BEGIN

     P_XML_OUT    := 'TEST1111';

     exception
     when others then
        P_XML_OUT   := 'LOAD_BL_REQ: Error'|| SQLERRM;
    END;
```

C# Code:

```
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = OraConnection;
    cmd.CommandText = "IBS.BNT_EQ.LOAD_BL_REQ_2";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    OracleParameter result = new OracleParameter();
    result.ParameterName = "P_XML_OUT";
    result.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob;
    result.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(result);

    OracleParameter XMLString = new OracleParameter();
    XMLString.ParameterName = "P_XML";
    XMLString.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
    XMLString.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

    OracleDataReader dr;

    cmd.Transaction = OraConnection.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        XMLString.Value = XML;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(XMLString);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cmd.Transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
        Log(2, "Transaction fail, exception: " + ex.ToString());
        ORADisconnect();
        return "";
    }
```

At debug process i see for dr:

```
    Depth: 0
    FetchSize: 131072
    FieldCount: 0
    HasRows: false
```

For test i add count code:

```
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        count++;
    }
```

Count is 0 in any times.

This code (for example):

```
  if(dr.IsDBNull(0))
  {
   //etc...
  }
```

or

```
  OracleClob oclob;
  oclob = dr.GetOracleClob(0);
```

return exception:

```
  dr.isdbnull exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
  at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i)
  at GlobalFunc.ORA_BlackList_Test(String XML) in c:\inetpub\project\App_Code\GlobalFunc.cs:line 474
```

At final i need to retrieve CLOB data from Oracle SP, but now stopped at this step.
Use: Visual Studio 2012, ASP.Net (web project, but i write this code to WinForms application and have a same problem), oracle.dataaccess.dll 4.112.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution! However, all is very simple:

```
        string XML = "XML Data";
        OracleCommand cmd = OraConnection.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "IBS.BNT_EQ.LOAD_BL_REQ_2";

        OracleParameter result = new OracleParameter();
        result.ParameterName = "P_XML";
        result.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob;
        result.Value = XML;
        result.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(result);

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }

        string str = (result.Value as OracleClob).Value;
        MessageBox.Show("Val: " + str);

        OraConnection.Close();
```

May be it be useful for someone.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i needed:  string str = (result.Value as OracleClob).Value;

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `dataReader.Read()` to actually get some data from a `DataReader`.

Also note that ODP.NET by default ignores parameter names and binds by position. That means that in your excample the parameters are wrong. Call `cmd.BindByName = true` after creating the command or add them in the correct order to the `Parameters` collection of the command.

Comment: Add `cmd.BindByName = true`, but nothing changed.
I try this code: 
        <code>while (dr.Read())
        {
            count++;
        }</code>
count is 0...

Comment: @PavelShaposhnikov Then of course `dr.IsDBNull` throws an `InvalidOperationException` since you read over the whole result set. The last call to `dr.Read()` didn't return any data so `dr.IsDBNull` has nothing to work on. Call `dr.IsDBNull` inside that loop (or better change the loop to a single `dr.Read` call since there will never be more than one result row for that procedure).

Comment: cremor, trouble not about `dr.IsDBNull`, trouble about empty returns from SP. I added the last code for demonstration for no data returned. As a result, `dr.IsDBNull` give exception in any times, call i'm `dr.Read()` or not... If i add `dr.GetOracleClob(0)` (it's my final target) instead of `dr.IsDBNull`, i catch exception too. I'm edit main post for better view of this.

Answer (score 0):

[Procedure view,,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlPF3.png) Thanks, RUN!

```
 protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=XE;Persist Security Info=True;Password=*****;User ID=WINCELL");
        string procedure = "WINCELL_API.ADD_CAMPAIGN";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(procedure, conn);
       // DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       // OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();

        string xml = "<campaign>";
        xml += "\n";
        xml += "<campaignInfo>";
        xml += "\n";
        xml += "<name>" + TextBox1.Text + "</name>";
        xml += "\n";
        xml += "<startDate>" + TextBox2.Text + "</startDate>";
        xml += "\n";
        xml += "<period>" + TextBox3.Text + "</period>";
        xml += "\n";
        xml += "<handsetStatu>" + TextBox4.Text + "</handsetStatu>";
        xml += "\n";
        xml += "<ServiceID>" + TextBox5.Text + "</ServiceID>";
        xml += "\n";
        xml += "</campaignInfo>";
        xml += "\n";
        xml += "</campaign>";


        TextBox6.Text = xml;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "";
            param.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob;
            param.Value = xml;
            param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            try
            {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            Label1.Text = error" + ex.ToString();

            }
        //string str = (param.Value as OracleClob).Value;
        //Label1.Text = "val: " + str;
    }
```